# Delphi interface generic function - Is there a work around?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface

I have the following code

```
IProxy<T> = interface
  ['{1E3A98C5-78BA-4D65-A4BA-B6992B8B4783}']
  function Setup : ISetup<T>;
  function Proxy : T;
  function CastAs<I : IInterface> : IInterface;
end;
```

Is there a way to work around the compiler error that is received when compiling?

"[DCC Error] Delphi.Mocks.pas(123): E2535 Interface methods must not have parameterized methods"

Basically I would like to have this interface be passed around and be able to cast off it, by passing in the type to cast to and having that type returned. I can achieve this with a class, however would prefer passing around an interface.

Additional Info:

Say I have the following class

```
TInterfaceProxy<T> = class(TBaseProxy<T>)
private type
  TProxyVirtualInterface = class(TVirtualInterface)
  private
    FProxy : TInterfaceProxy<T>;
  protected
  public
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HRESULT; override; stdcall;
    constructor Create(AProxy : TInterfaceProxy<T>; AInterface: Pointer; InvokeEvent: TVirtualInterfaceInvokeEvent);
  end;
private
  FVirtualInterfaces : TDictionary<TGUID, TProxyVirtualInterface>;
protected
  function InternalQueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HRESULT; stdcall;
  function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HRESULT; override;
  function Proxy : T;override;
  function CastAs<I: IInterface> : I;
public
  constructor Create;override;
  destructor Destroy;override;
end;
```

CastAs works well here as the newly requested cast can be created a new virtual interface. Now if I want to pass this class around its fine. However if I require it as an interface i.e. `TInterfaceProxy<T> = class(TBaseProxy<T>, IProxy<T>)` it doesn't work understand that. Don't agree with it, but understand.

Therefore how do I get around this restriction so that I can call a CastAs function, pass in a type (any interface type to start with), and be able to create a virtual interface from it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interfaces do not support generic parameterized methods, as the compiler says.

There is no workaround because it's a fundamental limitation. Parameterized methods in classes are implemented by adding one method per instantiation to the class. That works for classes since they are concrete, but is not viable for interfaces. That's because interfaces are a table of functions and the size of that table cannot vary depending on which generic method instantiations happen to be present elsewhere in the code. For similar reasons, generic methods cannot be virtual or dynamic.

The code in your question is a little mis-leading also. You wrote:

```
function CastAs<I : IInterface> : IInterface;
```

but I'm sure you meant:

```
function CastAs<I : IInterface> : I;
```

In any case, it's not possible. One option is to use a class instead. I agree that this is a bind.

If you want to do it in an interface, the best you can do is:

```
function CastAs(const IID: TGUID): IInterface;
```

But you'd have to call it like this:

```
MyIntf := ProxyIntf.CastAs(IMyIntf) as IMyIntf;
```

which feels somewhat foul.

Choose your poison!

Comment: Thanks. Believe I will have to go for the TGUID passing, and live with that. Also will expose the class externally, but keep the interface "function CastAs(const IID: TGUID): IInterface;" internal. Wish I could "Program into Your Language, Not in it" http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/what-are-the-key-points-of-code-complete

Comment: Also yes your correct about the `function CastAs<I : IInterface> : I;` a mistake on my copying the code over.

Answer (score 8):

As the error message states, a method in an interface cannot have Generic parameters.  The compiler simply does not support it, and this is documented as such:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Overview_of_Generics

> **Parameterized method in interface**
>
> A parameterized method (method declared with type parameters) cannot be declared in an interface.

In other words, your `CastAs` method is illegal because it is declared in an interface type.  On the other hand, you don't need such a method in the first place.  You can use `SysUtils.Supports()` instead for casting one interface to another.

Comment: Understand, not directly the issue. Realize what the compiler is saying, and why its an issue for Delphi. Don't agree with the design, however looking for a why to do my design with working around the limitations of Delphi. Currently I am thinking passing the object is the only way sadly. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following compiles for me with Delphi 11.0 (yet to see if it crashes):

```
TStoryItemList = TList<IStoryItem>;

TObjectListEx<T: class> = class
    class function GetAllOfInterface<AInterface: IInterface>(const list: TList<T>): TList<AInterface>;
  end;

//...

class function TObjectListEx<T>.GetAllOfInterface<AInterface>(const list: TList<T>): TList<AInterface>;
var
  itemAsAInterface: AInterface;
begin
  var guid := TRttiInterfaceType(TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(AInterface))).GUID;
  var listOfAInterface := TList<AInterface>.Create;
  for var item in list do
    if Supports(item, guid, itemAsAInterface) then
      listOfAInterface.Add(itemAsAInterface);
  result := listOfAInterface;
end;
```

usage

```
function TStoryItem.GetStoryItems: TStoryItemList;
begin
  result := TObjectListEx<TControl>.GetAllOfInterface<IStoryItem>(Controls);
end;
```

Comment: This is an older excerpt (made a bit more powerful now accepting TPredicate<T> and TPredicate<AInterface> optional filters) from my Delphi generics-based unit Zoomicon.Generics.Collections, currently at the repository of an App I'm developing: https://github.com/Zoomicon/READCOM_App/ (will probably move to its own repository in the future)